# Chef: database migration not run in application recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using application and application_ruby recipes. And I am defining my app like this with migrate 'true':

```
application 'railsapp' do
  owner 'vagrant'
  group 'vagrant'
  path '/home/vagrant/railsapp'
  revision 'master'
  repository 'git@github.com:rohshall/railsreadings.git'
  migrate true
  rails do
    bundler true
    database do
      host 'localhost'
      username mysql_connection_info[:username]
      password mysql_connection_info[:password]
      database 'railsreadings_production'
      adapter 'mysql2'
      encoding 'utf8'
    end
  end
  unicorn do
    worker_processes 2
  end
end
```

However, I don't see any migration running. I think it is because application_ruby removes it once it is run. However, in my case, there was a problem in database user credentials and the migration was not successful. Apart from running the migration manually, is there any way I can make it run?

```
ruby_block "remove_run_migrations" do
    block do
      if node.role?("#{new_resource.name}_run_migrations")
        Chef::Log.info("Migrations were run, removing role[#{new_resource.name}_run_migrations]")
        node.run_list.remove("role[#{new_resource.name}_run_migrations]")
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into the same issue, after declaring the migration command, it did work. So like this:

```
application 'railsapp' do
  owner 'vagrant'
  group 'vagrant'
  path '/home/vagrant/railsapp'
  revision 'master'
  repository 'git@github.com:rohshall/railsreadings.git'
  migrate true
  migration_command "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
  rails do
    bundler true
    database do
       host 'localhost'
       username mysql_connection_info[:username]
       password mysql_connection_info[:password]
       database 'railsreadings_production'
       adapter 'mysql2'
       encoding 'utf8'
    end
   end
  unicorn do
    worker_processes 2
  end
end
```